# How do you prevent thrust::reduce_by_key from writing to pageable memory?

Tags: c++, cuda, reduce, thrust

I am writing an application which uses several concurrent CUDA streams.  My other streams are blocking when my `thrust::reduce_by_key` call appears to write to pageable memory. I think the returned value is the problem.

How do you prevent the return value from being written to pageable memory?

I will include code that demonstrates my attempted solution.

```
#include <thrust/system/cuda/vector.h>
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/pair.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/reduce.h>
#include <thrust/random.h>

int main(void)
{
  int N = 20;
  thrust::default_random_engine rng;
  thrust::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(10, 99);

  // initialize data
  thrust::device_vector<int> array(N);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < array.size(); i++)
    array[i] = dist(rng);

  // allocate storage for sums and indices
  thrust::device_vector<int> sums(N);
  thrust::device_vector<int> indices(N);

  // make a pinned memory location for the returned pair of iterators
  typedef thrust::device_vector<int>::iterator  dIter;
  thrust::pair<dIter, dIter>*  new_end;

  const unsigned int bytes =  sizeof(thrust::pair<dIter, dIter>);
  cudaMallocHost((void**)&new_end, bytes);

  for(int i = 0 ; i< 20; i++){   // you can see in the profiler each operator writes 4 bytes to pageable memory

        *new_end = thrust::reduce_by_key
            (thrust::make_counting_iterator(0),
             thrust::make_counting_iterator(N),
             array.begin(),
             indices.begin(),
             sums.begin(),
             thrust::equal_to<int>(),
             thrust::plus<int>());
  }
  std::cout << "done \n";
  return 0;
}
```

This is a picture of my profiler showing the copy from device to host pageable memory
[image]

Comment: Just  a tip -- [SO] is a question and answer site. "I need help" isn't a question. The whole idea of this place is that you ask question which might be relevant and useful to the wider world. Someone  answers that question and the question and answer pair add to the corpus of potentially useful information available to everyone

Comment: Use cub::DeviceReduce::ReduceByKey  instead. Then you need to manage the copy to the host yourself and can use pinned memory for it.

Comment: I changed the title and text hoping to more closely reflect the purpose of Stack Overflow. I hope the answer to this question helps more developers than just me.

Comment: additional discussion [here](https://groups.google.com/g/thrust-users/c/mvqf9n5GKZk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am writing an application which uses several concurrent CUDA streams. My other streams are blocking when my `thrust::reduce_by_key` appears to write to pageable memory

This blocking behaviour is not caused by a "write to pageable memory". It is cause by an [explicit synchronization call](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/blob/0c81f42b296f0ead7e42055d7929a6dd695bc197/thrust/system/cuda/detail/reduce_by_key.h#L1044). In general, as of the CUDA 10.1 (Thrust 1.9.4) release, [all normal synchronous algorithms are blocking](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/releases/tag/1.9.4). You can confirm this yourself by examining an API trace with the profiler. However, you might be able to at least limit the scope of the blocking by launching the call into a [stream](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28537403/681865), although I am too lazy to test whether this modifies the behaviour of `cuda_cub::synchronize` in a useful way or not.

> How do you prevent the return value from being written to pageable memory?

Not that this is in any way related to your problem, but you can't. It is important to keep in mind that, contrary to what your original question asserted, `thrust::reduce_by_key` is not a kernel, it is host code which executes a series of operations, including [copying the return value from device memory to a host stack variable](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/blob/0c81f42b296f0ead7e42055d7929a6dd695bc197/thrust/system/cuda/detail/reduce_by_key.h#L1047). There is no programmer control over the internals, and obviously your attempt to use your own pinned memory value to accept a result passed by value is nonsensical and will have no effect.

As suggested in comments, if you need the level of granularity of control of internals of the operation that your question suggests, then thrust is the wrong choice. Use [cub::device::reduce_by_key](https://nvlabs.github.io/cub/structcub_1_1_device_reduce.html#a303ae673ac32825f95912b4bfff8bef1) -- that is the same algorithm implementation thrust uses, but you get explicit control over scratch memory, synchronization, streams, and how to access the result of the call. That is, however, not for beginners.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at my question. I am fine with the calls blocking a single stream and thread as that is expected behavior. I am using separate streams and launching the call into a stream does not change the behavior that is causing the problem.  The problem is when the return value is written from device memory to unpinned (pageable memory) it forces a cudaDeviceSynchronize which blocks all streams.  I guess any of the reduction transforms cause blocking across all streams.  I thought i must have been doing something wrong as I did not believe this was expected behavior.

Comment: "The problem is when the return value is written from device memory to unpinned (pageable memory) it forces a cudaDeviceSynchronize" -- that isn't what happens and is impossible. cuda_cub::synchronize resolves to a cudaDeviceSynchronize normally. I thought it might change to cudaStreamSynchronize  if a stream based execution policy was selected

Comment: As for "I did not believe this was expected behavior" -- think about it for a second. The result of the function is returned *by value*. How can it possibly do that without blocking the caller until that result is available? We are writing in imperative languages here

Comment: I am sorry I am not being clear.  I always believed the thread i was calling from and the stream I was using would be blocked. As you stated this is the only way it could work.  I had hoped that because I was separating my working threads and having each thread use a different stream I would not have a single reduce block all streams.         The only explanation I could find for this was a write from device to pageable memory.  I can’t think of a reason for stream directed reduce to need a device synchronize.  It should only need a streamSynchronize

Comment: When you look at the output from nvprof --print-api-trace you can clearly see a call to cudaDeviceSynchronize so I think your assumption that cuda_cub::synchronize resolves to cudaDeviceSynchronize is correct.  So thrust will not work for me in this instance   I had thought the write to pagable memory was causing implicit Synchronization.  I found a paper on CUDA http://www.cs.unc.edu/~tamert/papers/ecrts18b.pdf which looks well researched and states that writes to pageable memory do not implicitly synchronize.  Table 3.